How can I customize the \tcblower spearator in a jigsaw tcolorbox to make it a full line that respects top and bottom rule instead of the default?
As the title says, I'm trying to give a certain appearance to a jigsaw tcolorbox
The code I'm using, simplified for clarity, is
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\title{colorbox}
\author{Luca Ballarati}
\date{August 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback=0,opacitybacktitle=0,colback=white,size=fbox, colframe=red, boxrule=2pt, top=1ex, bottom=1ex, sidebyside, box align=top, sidebyside align=top]
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\tcblower
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}

You will notice the separator between the two parts is a dotted line that spans the whole height of the box.
What I want to achieve is a solid line that stops short of the top and bottom , and not for every tcolorbox, but only for jigsaw ones. Below is an example, although a more complicated one; look at the box on the right page and notice the line going down the middle:

How can I achieve this?

If you use an enhanced jigsaw, you can control the separation line via the segmentation code option:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  opacityback=0,
  opacitybacktitle=0,
  colback=white,
  size=fbox, 
  colframe=red, 
  boxrule=2pt, 
  top=1ex, 
  bottom=1ex, 
  sidebyside, 
  box align=top, 
  sidebyside align=top,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  segmentation code={
    \draw[shorten <=0.5cm,shorten >=0.5cm] (segmentation.south) -- (segmentation.north);
  }
]
\lipsum[2]
\tcblower
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}



Thanks! It works almost perfectly; the only thing I needed to change was the "shorten" part to "[shorten <=1ex, shorten >=1ex]" so it would be the same as the top and bottom rules
